# jQuery success:function{} issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

I have several 'select' elements on the page. When I choose some of  options, the ajax request is being sent to server and the element **adjacent to this 'select'** must be updated with response value. I expected the following code to be working:

```
$(".vars").live("change", function() { //selected something in <select> list
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url "someurl.php",
        data: {somedata},
        success: function(html) {
            $this.next().html(html); //this does not update .next() element.
        }
    });
});
```

If I replace

```
$(this).next().html(html);
```

with

```
alert(html);
```

I can see the ajax request was successful. Moreover, **it works only if there is only one 'select' on the page**, otherwise the empty pop-up appears.

Comment: In response to your comment below, to get/set the selected option of a select box, use .val() rather than .html().  Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that "this" isn't what you think it is while referenced in your callback.  Try this:

```
$(".vars").live("change", function() { //selected something in <select> list 
    var $driver = $(this);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url "someurl.php", 
        data: {somedata}, 
        success: function(html) { 
            $driver.next().html(html); //this does not update .next() element. 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you guys, but in case of several 'select' elements the 'html' response  turns out to be empty. Anyway, now we're closer to solution because at last the proper element is being triggered.

Comment: But it looks like some bug in server side code, so this question must be marked as "answered".

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".vars").live("change", function() { //selected something in <select> list
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url "someurl.php",
        data: {somedata},
        success: function(html) {
            $this.next().html(html); //this does not update .next() element.
        }
    });
});
```